# Jackson deserialization should succeed if additional fields are given but fail if fields are missing

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I've got this case class

```
case class Contact(id: String, firstName: String, lastName: String)
```

and I would like the Jackson Scala object mapper to fail when any of the three fields are missing eg:

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.readValue[Contact](""""{"id":"123","firstName":"John"}""")
```

but succeed when additional fields are given in the Json string eg:

```
mapper.readValue[Contact](""""{"id":"123","firstName":"John","lastName":"Test","age":"24"}""")
```

I did try using `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` and also  `mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)` but both options appears to disable the entire validation rather than just ignoring additional fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@JsonProperty(required=true)` would be the correct way to do this, but it is not implemented for deserialization yet.

[Javadoc says](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html):

> Note that as of 2.0, this property is NOT used by BeanDeserializer: support is expected to be added for a later minor version.

Ticket for this Feature: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/230

I would check the required values myself right after deserialization but maybe someone else can come up with a workaround.

Comment: According to the task it now works with construction injection. That allows you to use immutables, which is a good thing anyway. It does not work with properties as of today.